# Change sass variable depending on a body class

Tags: css, sass

Let's say I have an existing code base using sass variables i.e.

`$sw-primary-1: #ccc;`

and these classes are used all over the place i.e.

```
.lifecycle {
    &.new {
      background-color: $sw-primary-1:
    }
  }
}
```

Is there anything I can do a large existing code base like this where I know want to change this colour palette variables depending on a different class on the body.

i.e. `body class="redesign"`

where I basically want to go

```
.redesign {
  $sw-primary-1: blue;
}
```

But the above doesn't work it still sticks with the original sass variable color.

Comment: use CSS variable instead

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50731596/dynamically-change-a-variable-based-on-class-name/50731668#50731668

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52135505/appropriate-use-of-bem-in-css/52135600#52135600

Answer (score 5):

It works.
Note that you should use the **!global** flag as well.

> All variable assignments not at the top level of the document are now local by default. If there's a global variable with the same name, it won't be overwritten unless the !global flag is used. For example, $var: value !global will assign to $var globally. This behavior can be detected using feature-exists(global-variable-shadowing).

*[Source](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_CHANGELOG.html)*

```
$primary-color: blue;

.foo {
  color: $primary-color;
}

.bar {
  $primary-color: red !global;
  color: $primary-color;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to accomplish this is using mixins.

```
@mixin bkcolor($color) {
    background-color:$color;
}

.lifecycle {
    &.new {
      @include bkcolor('blue');
    }
  }
}
```