# changing a variable in SCSS not working in angular

Tags: css, angular, variables, sass, themes

```
// this variable is default or dark
$mode: default;
.dark-mode {
   $mode: dark !important;
}
.light-mode {
   $mode: default !important;
}
```

when I change the $mode to default or dark, it's working but when I use class .dark-mode or .light-mode not work

my code is below not working but when I change the $mode in Scss manual working
where is my problem ?

```
<div class="dark-mode">
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically change a variable based on class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50731596/dynamically-change-a-variable-based-on-class-name)

Comment: Hi. Can you share the html code where you're dynamically changing the class? I think you'll find `ngClass` helpful: https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass